# WebLogic autodeployed ear gone after Docker container restart

Tags: docker, weblogic, autodeploy

I have a WebLogic 12.1.2 image that I'm looking to auto deploy an application ear on to.

I can do this when building the image using the Dockerfile i.e.

COPY some.ear /u01/domains/mydomain/autodeploy

The container run using this image runs fine and I can reach my application REST interface with Postman.

However, if I restart that container, the autodeployed application no longer exists in the container's WebLogic console and hence Postman calls fail.
The ear file is still in the autodeploy directory on restart.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a little hack around this.

My container has the WebLogic autodeploy directory mounted to a host directory containing the ear. If I rename the ear e.g. rename some.ear some.ear.1 and rename it back to some.ear.1 to some .ear or cut/paste the ear to/from another directory then WebLogic can pick it up. It's not ideal but it works in case anyone else comes across the same issue.